# How do I add spacing to the images

Tags: html, css

My images seem to be stacking on each other and I'm trying to create some space in between them. I tried searching on other sites but nothing seems to work. Can someone check out whats wrong and help me?

CSS:

```css
DIV.contact
{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 140px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
<div style="line-height: 140px">
<div class="contact"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/72/49/29/724929194ddf777ebcc33278286dec62.jpg" width="240" height="160" hspace="50" vspace="2"></div>
<div class="contact"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/89/63/06/896306fa454110ae996fe43e3e9c7339.jpg" width="160" height="240" hspace="50" vspace="2"></div>
<div class="contact"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/80/2d/eb/802deb31195f94c0bdec3b06ac0dbd2a.jpg" width="220" height="220" hspace="50" vspace="2"></div>

<p>
<div class="contact"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/8f/95/41/8f9541f5845b6d2f31aec0c5f77fcf77.jpg" width="150" height="150" hspace="50" vspace="2"></div>
<div class="contact"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/51/7d/91/517d91c4e628e6f0b637d73584c4d8e4.jpg" width="190" height="140" hspace="50" vspace="2"></div>
<div class="contact"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/19/62/cb/1962cbc05ac837fb33b75e6556bb5df2.jpg" width="180" height="240" hspace="20" vspace="2"></div>
</p>
<p>
<div class="contact"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/41/e9/49/41e94905f208bfbcf015deadbe6de17a.jpg" width="240" height="180" hspace="50" vspace="2"></div>
<div class="contact"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/d0/37/83/d0378348dbb149eddb085ff3402cc072.jpg" width="140" height="190" hspace="50" vspace="2"></div>
<div class="contact"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/63/58/b2/6358b24f4ec875fcd64d965db44812e3.jpg" width="200" height="120" hspace="50" vspace="2"></div>
</p>
<p>
<div class="contact"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/26/0d/c8/260dc8231aa5cd36414330b7e7c9c55d.jpg" width="260" height="200" hspace="50" vspace="2"></div>
<div class="contact"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/de/2c/54/de2c546b3ff024eefedf1fe3af3c51cd.jpg" width="120" height="200" hspace="50" vspace="2"></div>
<div class="contact"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/9e/30/c9/9e30c9001ae7db58c431440d7a1cc0e1.jpg" width="190" height="240" hspace="50" vspace="2"></div>
</div> </p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Is because you set your div with to 160 and the images are wider.

Please add:

```
DIV.contact img
{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

When you remove the vspace and hspace, everything works as expected. Don't know why you use that.

Answer (score 0):

```
margin-top:20px; /*to have the space above the image*/
margin-bottom:20px; /*to have the space under the image*/
```

This should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: block;` and then make the divs float left.

Then just use `margin: a b c d;` to add spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `padding` to class `.contact`

```
.contact {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; // top,right,bottem,left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove width from CSS

```
DIV.contact
{
display: inline-block;
width: 140px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle
}
```

change it to

```
DIV.contact
{
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following approaches:

Padding:

```
DIV.contact
{
    padding: 20px; /*you can use % values as well {like: 2%;}*/
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

Margin:

```
DIV.contact
{
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to have all pictures you want in a row inside the same div. If you need several divs you have to do it another way. And in the future please write all css in a css file or in style element Its much easier to see all the code.

```css
img{
width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div style="line-height: 140px">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/72/49/29/724929194ddf777ebcc33278286dec62.jpg" width="240" height="160">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/89/63/06/896306fa454110ae996fe43e3e9c7339.jpg" width="160" height="240">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/80/2d/eb/802deb31195f94c0bdec3b06ac0dbd2a.jpg" width="220" height="220">
</div>

<div style="line-height: 140px">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/72/49/29/724929194ddf777ebcc33278286dec62.jpg" width="240" height="160">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/89/63/06/896306fa454110ae996fe43e3e9c7339.jpg" width="160" height="240">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/80/2d/eb/802deb31195f94c0bdec3b06ac0dbd2a.jpg" width="220" height="220">
</div>
<div style="line-height: 140px">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/72/49/29/724929194ddf777ebcc33278286dec62.jpg" width="240" height="160">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/89/63/06/896306fa454110ae996fe43e3e9c7339.jpg" width="160" height="240">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/80/2d/eb/802deb31195f94c0bdec3b06ac0dbd2a.jpg" width="220" height="220">
</div>
<div style="line-height: 140px">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/72/49/29/724929194ddf777ebcc33278286dec62.jpg" width="240" height="160">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/89/63/06/896306fa454110ae996fe43e3e9c7339.jpg" width="160" height="240">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/80/2d/eb/802deb31195f94c0bdec3b06ac0dbd2a.jpg" width="220" height="220">
</div>
```